# How to get value between 2 character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Id of '**2015-11-30_1112_3**'. How do I get the values between the two underscores(_) so I am left with '**1112**'.

Please note that the length of the string varies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simplest solution would be

```
var value = '2015-11-30_1112_3';
alert( value.split( "_" )[ 1 ] );
```

just split the variable, which should give you an array of 3 items. Second item is what you are looking for

Answer (score 4):

You can of course use a regular expression:

```
s.match(/_(.*)_/)[1]
```

**Explanation:** I assume `s` is your string. The expression matches everything, i.e. (.*), between two underscores. You have to select index 1 of the result because index 0 will give you the complete match including the underscores. Subsequent elements contain the bracketed groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are sure that all ids have the same format:

```
var str= '2015-11-30_1112_3';
var array=str.split("_");
alert(array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this..

```
var value = "2015-11-30_1112_3";
var value1 = value.match(/_(.+)_/g);
```

Demo : [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeeshmenoth/h3fwu944/)

Answer (score -1):

Please try below solution with the help of this solution you can find value between two different symbols as well.

```js
var str = "2015-11-30_1112_3";
var newStr = str.split('_')[1].split('_')[0];
alert(newStr);
```

Comment: why do you need the second split?

Comment: I added jQuery as a tag. This answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: second split in case if both symbols are different like need value between _ and @ then also it will work kind of generic solution.

Comment: Thanks @CottonSocksBro nice to hear it is working for you!!

Comment: Thanks @giorgio actually earlier I thought to include something more so added jquery reference, but now I removed!!

Comment: @CottonSocksBro If you need a generic solution, lex82's answer has a much better base, where doing like this, `value.match(/(_|@)(.*)(_|@)/)[2])`, would let you use an _ or an @ in any order still giving you the correct output.